# how to create custom slot for email address

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a custom slot for email address in alexa skill .
I even specified bulk of slot values consisting of various types of email address.
still , alexa doesn't recognize email address.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Getting an email address from the user's speech is not easy. The best way is to get user contact info from user permissions. [Refer here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html)